# Prevent sent emails treated as junk mails using php mail function

Tags: php, header, email, email-spam

I wrote a PHP script to send emails.

My script is like this:

```
$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: abc@yahoo.com' . "\r\n";

// Email Variables
$toUser  = "someone@yahoo.com"; // recipient
$subject = "testing"; // subject
$body    = "<html><body><p>
             Example of including an image via html \<img\> tag:
             <br>
             <img src='../images/profile.jpg'>
             <br>
             My new picture
             <br></p></body></html>"; // content

if (mail($toUser,$subject,$body,$headers)) {
    echo "sent";
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

Well, of course I use a valid email address for sender and receiver. I did receive the email, but it goes to junk mail. So I went for google research. Is it because of my "header" script problem? If it isn't, then what could cause my script to send a junk mail? Any solution?

Answer (score 15):

Please try this:

```
$headers ="From:<$from>\n";
$headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers.="Content-type: text/html; charset=iso 8859-1";

mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers,"-f$from");
```

Comment: You are a star @Anju

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps the problem is that yahoo uses [domainkeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys) verification, which will likely fail for your application given that the mail is not actually coming from yahoo's servers.

Answer (score 7):

When I've once had a similar problem I looked at the headers and found out that my host uses SpamAssassin. So I googled for 'SpamAssassin score' and found a multitude of information on how to incorrectly (and thus correctly) form an email.

For example: [SpamAssassin score list](http://spamassassin.apache.org/tests_3_2_x.html)

Answer (score 5):

**1. Check mail content**

As others have hinted it is probably marked as spam because your mail looks like spam.

I am not sure if you the script that you have posted is the actual one that you are testing.

If it has the actual mail body & headers, then running this message through a standard installation of SpamAssassin gives it a spam score of 4.9

```
X-Spam-Status: No, score=4.9 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_50,HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_04,
        HTML_MESSAGE,MIME_HTML_ONLY,NO_DNS_FOR_FROM,NO_RELAYS autolearn=no
        version=3.2.5
```

Since the email body has only HTML it has a greater chance of being handled with suspect by most anti-spam solutions.

**2. Mail server's IP**

Another aspect worth checking will be the IP address of your mail server. Any mail originating from dynamic IP addresses will potentially be considered as SPAM.

**3. Blocklists**

Also check if your IP address is listed in one of the block lists. To start with please check your IP address with http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso.

Answer (score 3):

Use [mxtoolbox.com](http://mxtoolbox.com/) to check the servers IP to be blacklisted or not. As well this website can help you with a couple of email related checks.

Of course there are a long list of checks running inside spam filters. As already suggested, check the email headers for details about the spam filters rating of the spam email.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

```
                   **This Works Perfectly fine for me**     
                        $to="reciever@reciever.com";
                        $subject="This is Your Message";
                        $from = 'Sender <noreply@sender.com>';
                        $body='Hi '.$name.', <br/><br>Now You can See Yor main in inbox';
                        $headers = "From: " .($from) . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= "Reply-To: ".($from) . "\r\n";
                        $headers .= "Return-Path: ".($from) . "\r\n";;
                        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
                        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
                        $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
                        $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";
                        mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem:

The problem is that when you specify content-type before the "From:" part , the mail comes as a spam.

But if you specify "From:" before the content part it comes as a normal mail and makes you smile and curious.

Answer (score 1):

As schnalle said, one problem surely is that the smtp server that you use to send the email and the one thet you specify as From, is different.. the from's domain whould be the same that the server youre running on.

So, you can use the yahoo server to send the email (check if they allow the smtp remote connection, but i guess they do) connecting by smtp, and this will solve 1 problem.

Another one is the html contents without the alternative plain text contents, but, this one is less important.

I suggest you [phpMailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/), free and open-source php class to send email, easly to use (i use it event o send mail through gmail server)

Answer (score 1):

1. On your server try to sort your SPF (Sender Policy Framework, Google for SPF record)  record out.
2. Make sure you send your e-mails from an existing account on your server/domain.
3. Make sure you have the reply-to address in your header.

These are the basic things you can try.

Answer (score 1):

if your website domain is mydomain.com then in From headers make sure to use someone@mydomain.com

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Content-type: text/html` and add `$headers .= "X-Priority: 2\nX-MSmail-Priority: high";`  to get rid of Spam. This method has been tried and tested.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is, the server you're sending the mail from is not a yahoo server. most spam filters check if they match, otherwise it would (and is - or was) possible to easily fake the sender. ever wondered why you get spam from bill.gates AT microsoft.com or your own mail address?

Answer (score 0):

You've got two solutions:

- use Yahoo's SMTP using abc@yahoo.com credentials to send mail from abc@yahoo.com;
- use other from, with your own domain;

Answer (score 0):

You can try the mail class and test file that I have created here. I have tested the files and can send emails to my hotmail and gmail under a different mail name. The main reason why the emails are mark as junk is because the structure (both header and message) is not correctly done. In most cases, it is the line feed that is causing the problem.

I can use it to send mail with attachments to Gmail. However, the attachments dont work for hotmail. Hope this helps =)

You can check the files [here](http://chernkuan.blogspot.com/2010/12/php-send-mail-with-attachments-using.html)..