# Created a registration form with automated email confirmation but emails keep being sent to the junk folder of the recipients email. Any ideas?

Tags: php, email, spam, activation

Here is the following information i'm sending the user.

Sender email: Support@photocrayze.com

Subject: PhotoCrayze - Account Activation Instructions‏

Message:

image url goes here

Hello {FIRSTNAME} {LASTNAME},

**Thank you for signing up for for photocrayze.com!**

**What's Next?**

- Click here to activate your account
- Upload 15MB photographs to your account and the community
- Share your portfolio with your friends

Here are your log in details...

Username: {USERNAME}
         Password: as entered on the registration page

Thank you for choosing photocrayze for your photo sharing experience!

Sincerely,
         The PhotoCrayze Team
         http://www.photocrayze.com/">www.photocrayze.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Previously on StackOverflow:

- [Prevent sent emails treated as junk mails using php mail function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746809/prevent-sent-emails-treated-as-junk-mails-using-php-mail-function)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032552/php-mail-sends-straight-to-spam-box
- [PHP mail stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892409/php-mail-problem)
- [Troubleshooting PHP Mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658043/troubleshooting-php-mail)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800898/phphow-to-avoid-a-system-generated-email-going-into-spam