# send email in php using xampp server?

Tags: php, email, smtp

i want to send email using php through xampp server.here is my code

```
<?php
$to = 'atchibabu@solbaacken.com';
$subject = 'My Email';
$msg = "please find details";
// Make sure to escape quotes
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: My Site Name <atchibabu516@gmail.com.com>' . "\r\n";
if(mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers))
{
echo "success";
}
else
{
echo "fail";
}
?>
```

when i execute i get "success" message but i didn't get any mail i am waiting still one hour 
i don't know why it's happening. some suggestions send email using smtp so can any one guide how could i use the smtp.i am using mac xampp so any one guide me i could i install smtp in mac xammp.

thanks for advance.

Comment: Have you checked your junk mail folder?

Comment: Are your Xampp server configured with smtp settings

Comment: hey thanks for quick response.i am not having much experience on that can you tell me where the folder is placed. i will check

Comment: het @Hameed.i don't know check that i could i check my xampp server configured with smtp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to note:

Your from has 2 `.com` so, probability of your message going in [SPAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spam) is almost 90%.

Check your [phpinfo();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) output. What does sendmail_path show? Do you have that software installed? Ideally it is `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` and the software is `sendmail` in ubuntu machines.
 Also, in your phpinfo(), check the SMTP port. Also there is a high possibility of getting blocked by a firewall or similar software, checked it already?

Comment: hey perfect.just now i check spam i get email.SMTP port is 25.so what to do get emails inbox.please guide me

Comment: If this worked for you, click on the 'tick' next to the answer! About Inbox part then you have to make sure that you pass correct headers. Besides, the headers which I see here seem to be correct. On live server with valid resolving hostname, it should work :)

Comment: so why it's happing emails going to spam in local host is any thing wrong in header can you guide me

Comment: hi @karmicdice: do you have any idea get email in inbox

Comment: that is what I said? your IP address is 127.0.0.1 which resolves to hostname localhost. Then, there are IP address which will resolve to your domain name, for example ip of yahoo.com will resolve to yahoo.com... localhost is not a valid hostname when it comes to WAN... So have a hosting, have a domain, and use the script! it will not go in spam.

Comment: One simple Question: Have you started Mercury so that your mails can get processed?

Comment: Ages ago! But, that is irrelevant to the current answer. Google for Dan Murphy's tutorial on Mercury XAMPP. It is easy one :)

Answer (score 1):

You should configure your email on localhost
here is the step by step way to configure your smtp

1. Open the “php.ini“. You should know where it is located because it depends upon the particular server you’re running.
2. Search for the attribute called “SMTP” in the php.ini file.Generally you can find the line “SMTP=localhost“. change the localhost to the smtp server name of your ISP. And, there is another attribute called “smtp_port” which should be set to 25.I’ve set the following values in my php.ini file.

   > ```
   >     SMTP = smtp.wlink.com.np  
   >     smtp_port = 25
   > ```
3. Restart the apache server so that PHP modules and attributes will be reloaded.
4. Now try to send mail

[Reff link is here](http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html)

**helpfull links**
http://expertester.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-send-email-from-xampp-php/

Comment: hey thanks for response.can you tell me way is ISP SMTP = smtp.wlink.com.np  
    smtp_port = 25 what could i put here

Comment: i am all ways get email in spam only

Comment: yea but why it's going to spam

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746809/prevent-sent-emails-treated-as-junk-mails-using-php-mail-function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800898/php-how-to-avoid-a-system-generated-e-mail-going-into-spam

Comment: May these link will help you to found the Answer of your new question :) Cheers Man

Answer (score 0):

Edit your SMTP. If you  want to test it in your localhost, try installing Mozilla Thunderbird for localhost email and create new account using Mercury from Xampp.