# PHP mail goes in spam and inbox

Tags: php, email, spam

I am using simple PHP mail function to send mail. Here is my code:

```
sendEmail('xyz@gmail.com', 'test subject', 'test body', 'xyz name', 'abc@gmail.com', 'HTML');

function sendEmail($to, $subject, $body, $fromName, $from, $format = '')
{
    $headers = '';

    if($format=='HTML')
    {
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    }

    $headers .= "From: $fromName <$from>" . "\n";

    $success = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f no-reply@xyz.com');
    return $success;

}
```

My problem is this when i send more than one (like 10) mail then some mail goes into spam and some in inbox. If script is wrong then all mail should go into spam or if right then all mail into inbox.

Why some mail goes into spam and some in inbox?

while subject, body, message and email(to) is same.

Comment: You should look into an authenticated SMTP solution that uses proper rDNS, DKIM, and SPF records.

Comment: Read this article http://www.activecampaign.com/help/improving-delivery/

Comment: why not try to sending mail with `phpmailer` or `swiftmailer` libraries.

Comment: Jogesh_pi: I tried phpmailer and it's working for all email server but not working for hotmail server.

Comment: Add headers to your sending email function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use full headers to avoid spam

http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/avoid-spam-filters-with-php-mail-emails/

[Prevent sent emails treated as junk mails using php mail function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746809/prevent-sent-emails-treated-as-junk-mails-using-php-mail-function)