# Mail go to spam intead of inbox using smtp mail method in php

Tags: php, smtp

I want to send mail  with smtp mail method using PHP.Now mail go to spam instead of inbox,i am using smtp mail method.I had set the hostname,username and password.

```
  <?php

  define("SMTP_HOST", "mail.test.net"); //Hostname of the mail server
  define("SMTP_PORT", "25"); //Port of the SMTP like to be 25, 80, 465 or 587
  define("SMTP_UNAME", "tttt"); 
  //Username for SMTP authentication any valid   email created in your domain
  define("SMTP_PWORD", "tttt"); //Password for SMTP authentication
  ?>

   //smtp mail
  $mail   = new PHPMailer;
  $mail->Host = SMTP_HOST; 
  $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT; 
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
  $mail->Username = SMTP_UNAME; 
  $mail->Password = SMTP_PWORD; 
  $mail->AddReplyTo("test@test.com", "zamisoft"); 
  $mail->SetFrom("test@test.com", "zamisoft.com"); 
  $mail->Subject = $subject; 
  $mail->AddAddress($to, '');
  $mail->MsgHTML($message);
  $send = $mail->Send(); 
  $mail->ClearAddresses();

  //smtp mail
```

Anybody give any solution for these issue?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20416866/php-mail-goes-in-spam-and-inbox and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229279/sending-email-via-php-mail-function-goes-to-spam

Comment: check this too http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/avoid-spam-filters-with-php-mail-emails/

Answer (score 0):

There is a very similar question here regarding using PHPMailer and Spam - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16717647/1676190

> This does sound more like a configuration issue with your mail server
>   and/or your DNS server. Your mail server does not appear to be
>   "trusted" enough, so you don't get enough "positive" points from GMail
>   (and mail clients). I notice that you're using postfix as your
>   mailer... Have you configured it properly?
>
> I would suggest you configure postfix first. For example, here's a
>   guide on how to do it in CentOS:
>
> http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix
>
> Second, you should add an SPF record to your DNS server:
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework
>
> Third, it would be good to have a reverse lookup entry for your
>   server:
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup
>
> You will need to do the above and some more to make sure that clients
>   don't flag your mail as spam, and you don't get blacklisted
>
> Here's a good list of things to do to avoid getting blacklisted:
>
> http://www.supportsages.com/blog/2010/07/prevent-your-mailip-from-getting-marked-as-spamblacklisted-a-few-tips/