# How avoid mail go to spam instead of inbox using php?

Tags: php

My mail go to spam instead of inbox using PHP.I want to go mail to inbox.Anybody have any solution for these issue?

My header code is given beow.

```
$header_mail="select * from mail_header";
$header_mail2=mysql_query($header_mail);
$fet=mysql_fetch_array($header_mail2);
$content=$fet['content'];

$Headers = "From:$content\r\n" . 
"Reply-To: $content\r\n" . 
"Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 \r\n";
$Headers.= "MIME-version: 1.0\n";
$Headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset= iso-8859-1\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

use smtp authentication. Follow  the link for full source code

[smtp mailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple cases for the span mailer. Please find below the things which would be useful to find out problem:

Check your mail body

- Avoid phrases and wording spammers commonly use.
- Avoid using all upper-case words in the message subject.
- Do not use (too) many images.
- Properly balance your pictures size with the text size.
- Avoid using HTML tags that could increase your spam score, e.g. iframe tags, multiple large font tags and/or color font tags (better use inline CSS styles instead).
- Avoid using scripts in your messages, like javascript, vbscript.
- Correct any HTML coding errors in your messages, since these too will increase your spam score.

Avoid sending attachments other than pdf, gif, jpg and png

Check your Domain Name Server (DNS) configuration

Customize your messages

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> full details of how to avoid mails go to spam.please follows the given links:

http://www.velvetblues.com/web-development-blog/avoid-spam-filters-with-php-mail-emails/

http://www.000webhost.com/forum/scripts-code-snippets/26120-send-emails-inbox-avoid-spam-using-php.html

[Prevent sent emails treated as junk mails using php mail function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746809/prevent-sent-emails-treated-as-junk-mails-using-php-mail-function)