# Mail Delivery failed when using anchor element in HTML email using PHP

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

I am using pear lib for sending an email and getting three issues when I am sending any emails from Gmail using PHP.

1) I am getting HTML code in the email.

2) If I am using any anchor element then email delivery failed.// without anchor element it is working.

3) The anchor element link is not working in iPhone.// for iPhone i tried

```
require_once "mail/Mail.php";
  $to = $email;
  $from = 'user@gmail.com';
  $subject = 'Test!';
  $body = "<html><head><title>HTML email</title></head>
        <body>
        <a href='domain.com/changepassword.php?user_id=" .$User_id1."'>Create your password here</a>
        </body>
        </html>";// HTML code is display in email
       $headers = array(
           'From' => $from,
            'To' => $to,
            'Subject' => $subject
        );
   $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
                'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                'port' => '465',
                'auth' => true,
                'username' => 'user@gmail.com',
                'password' => '******'
            ));

    $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
        if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
            echo('<p>' . $mail->getMessage() . '</p>');
        } else {
            echo('<p>Message successfully sent!</p>');
        }
```

Comment: Where is this anchor tag link you speak of?

Comment: I added in $body. if i remove that the it is working but also getting html code

Answer (score 2):

You have to define in header for html. Hope you will get solution here: [how to send html mails using PEAR mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361762/how-to-send-html-mails-using-pear-mail)

Add http in link to make it workable for all cases.

I use phpmailer which is always fine. You can try this one. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Mehedee, Before I tried PHP mailer but my all emails goes to spam

Comment: Using smtp server resolves this issue. You can ask your server admin to get smtp server or you can use 3rd party smtp like pepipost.com but it will take time to approve.

Comment: I am using Gmail for sending mail using PHP

Comment: Strong filtration is used there - whitelist, redlist email. In some cases spam filter consider gmail as spam. You can test your from email here. Then you can understand clearly https://www.mail-tester.com/

Comment: Mr.Mehedee you can check my PHPMailer code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41361169/sending-email-from-php-using-smtp-and-email-goes-to-spam-what-will-be-easiest-wa

Comment: I don't know why my all emails goes to spam

Comment: Why it is not working check here mail-tester.com. It will provide analysis report of your email. How you test: 1. send email to "web-r1ief@mail-tester.com" from your script. 2. Then click on button to see analysis report. Also you can try with email containing same domain. Your server admin will suggest.

Comment: Mr.Mehedee i tried on http://mailtester.com/ and it showing some message Server doesn't allow e-mail address verification in yellow color

Answer (score 1):

How about trying this in your `$body`. Also remember that there should be no spaces after $body line (where `DOCTYPE` is declared).

I used this on SendGrid and PHPMailer.

```
$body = <<<EOD
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    Your content here
  </body>
</html>
EOD;
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Nick, I tried but still getting HTML code in email